# Get Array Index from JSON data SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

```
{
    "Name": ["dokumen_1","dokumen_2","dokumen_3","dokumen_4"],
    "Date": [0,0,0,0],
    "Progress": [0,0,0,0]
}
```

I want to fetch `Date` and `Progress` value according to `Name` position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `date` and `progress` values for a better illustration

**NOTE:  in 2016 the JSON_VALUE has to be a literal**

**Example**

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max) = '
{
"Name":["dokumen_1","dokumen_2","dokumen_3","dokumen_4"],
"Date":[1,2,3,4],
"Progress":[11,12,13,12]
}'


Select Name     = value
      ,Date     = JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.Date['+[key]+']')
      ,Progress = JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.Progress['+[key]+']')
 From  openjson(@JSON,N'$.Name')
```

**Results**

```
Name        Date    Progress
dokumen_1   1       11
dokumen_2   2       12
dokumen_3   3       13
dokumen_4   4       12
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and what if I will only retrieve data based on the name "dokumen_3"

Comment: @IrvanAffandy  Just add WHERE value='dokumen_3'

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is a combination of `OPENJSON()` with default schema and appropriate `JOIN`s. Of course, you need at least SQL Server 2016 to use the built-in JSON support.

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max) = '
{
"Name":["dokumen_1","dokumen_2","dokumen_3","dokumen_4"],
"Date":[101,102,103,104],
"Progress":[201,202,203,204]
}'

SELECT n.[value] AS Name, d.[value] AS Date, p.[value] AS Progress
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Name') n
LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@json, '$.Date') d ON n.[key] = d.[key]
LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@json, '$.Progress') p ON n.[key] = p.[key]
```